# Is it possible to find inside of Default PHP Functions?

Tags: php, function

Is there way to find inside of Default PHP Functions?

Ex : `number_format();` function.

I know that what is the purpose of `number_format()` function and when should I use it. But I would like to know is there way to find what is the inside of `number_format();` function, that means inside of the `number_format()` function.

Comment: What you want to find inside `number_format();`

Comment: check `number_format();` documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)